# Wordpress Plugin CSS style sheet shows up correctly in some themes but not others

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, wp-enqueue-scripts

I'm writing a custom wordpress plugin, and am trying to enqueue the plugin's CSS style. Currently testing in my local WP instance.

1. The styling is **partially** working in the Twenty Twenty Two theme (the dashicons are showing correctly, style doesn't work),
2. is **not** working in the Twenty Twenty theme (neither dashicons nor style are showing up),
3. but it **is** working properly in the Twenty Twenty One theme.

Here is the code:

```
function comment_rating_styles() {

    wp_register_style( 'comment-rating-styles', plugins_url( '/' , __FILE__ ) . 'assets/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'dashicons' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'comment-rating-styles' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'comment_rating_styles' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be possible that something in the theme overwrites or disables the dashicons or the comment styles. You can try to add a higher priority, so it gets executed later.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'comment_rating_styles', 999 );
```